# Is Ω(f+g) = Ω(min(f,g))?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

We know that $O(f(n)+g(n))=O(max(f(n),g(n)))$.

So can we say that $\Omega(f(n)+g(n)) = \Omega(min(f(n),g(n))$?
Then what is $\Theta(f(n)+g(n))$ equal to?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming $f,g > 0$, we have
$$\max(f(x),g(x)) < f(x) + g(x) \leq 2\max(f(x),g(x)).$$
Therefore $\Theta(f(x) + g(x)) = \Theta(\max(f(x),g(x)))$, in the sense that both sets of functions are equal.

Still assuming that $f,g > 0$, it is also true that $\Omega(f(x)+g(x)) = \Omega(\min(f(x),g(x)))$, in the sense that if $h(x) \in \Omega(f(x)+g(x))$ then also $h(x) \in \Omega(\min(f(x),g(x))$. The stronger bound $\Omega(f(x)+g(x)) = \Omega(\max(f(x),g(x)))$ also holds.

I have mentioned two interpretations of equality. In fact the second one (which really corresponds to $\subseteq$ in this case) is actually the standard one – equality is not symmetric! However, in the case of big $\Theta$ both notions fortunately coincide.

Comment: Thanks for making this clear ! So ultimately both Ω(min(f(x),g(x)) and Ω(max(f(x),g(x))) holds right?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: I think you should be able to answer such questions yourself now.

Comment: Please fix, @RickyDemer's answer looks correct to me (and disagrees with your's).

Comment: @vonbrand We have different interpretations of $=$.

Answer (score 2):

"So can we say that $\Omega(f(n)+g(n)) = \Omega(\min(f(n),g(n))$?"

No. (Consider 1 and n.)

"Then what is $\Theta(f(n)+g(n))$ equal to?"

If $f$ and $g$ can have opposite signs then $O(\max(f(n),g(n)))$, else $\Theta(\max(f(n),g(n)))$.

Comment: then what is Ω (f(n)+g(n))?

Comment: f(n)=Ω(n) and g(n)=Ω($n^2$) then what is the value of Ω(f(n)+g(n)).

Comment: I guess the "No" answers the first question mark, and the second line answers the second one. However, this is not immediate, and this answer should be expanded to provide more context.

Comment: Can u help me with the above question? I explicitly stated what f(n) and g(n) is ! I am currently having problems grasping the concept! @Ricky Demer

Comment: @user3932852 Unfold the definitions. There's not more to it.

Comment: Can I think in this way? In Ω(n) + Ω($n^2$), we only care about the dominant term , and here the dominant term is the minimum of n and $n^2$ (in Big Oh its the maximum) and hence the answer is Ω(n)?

Comment: @user3932852 : ​ We only care about the dominant term, but even for Ω, the dominant term is still the maximum. ​ ​ ​ ​